# Connecting to PostgreSQL Data Source in SQL Server Import Export Tool

Tags: postgresql, odbc

I'm trying to setup an easily-replicable (or even manual and I do it once a month or so) process for moving data from a large Azure PostgreSQL database to a more manageable Azure SQL database for end users that are most familiar with SQL Server. I've successfully connected to the PostgreSQL database via PGAdmin, so I know all my connection string info.

I started by installing the latest ODBC driver from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/).

I then used a connection string which was given to me from the Azure portal, filled in the proper database name and password, and attempted to use the following drivers:

- PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(UNICODE)
- PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(ANSI)

I am getting the following error with either of them:

```
ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

[image: Data source name not found and no default driver specified]

What step am I missing in this process? Or how best can I troubleshoot this?

After more research, I attempted to add the ODBC driver here:
[image]

And got the following error (I'm not sure why Tableau is relevant to this?):
[image]

Thank you.